# How can I loop over multiple query parameters and use with ng-if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS I am sending a user to a page that has a query string based on employees they selected on a previous page. I am splitting the query string to log the variable, `$scope.splitusers`, which logs an array of `user.ID`s such as ["14", "21"] passed from the previous page. I want to use ng-if when user.ID from the DOM equals user from the JS. In the HTML, I want to use `ng-if` and show user's info when `user.ID == splitusers`. This works now when only one `user.ID` is in the query string, but is broken when more than one user is selected.

Here is the HTML that is currently broken:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="ProfileSheet" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-if="user.ID == splitusers">
      <table id="Profile">
        <tr>
          <th>User</th>
          <td>{{user.Title}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q){
    var getQueryString = function (field, url){
        var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
        var reg = new RegExp('[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i');
        var string = reg.exec(href);
        return string ? string[1] : null;
    }
    $scope.selectedusers = getQueryString('users', window.location.href)
    $scope.splitusers = $scope.selectedusers.split(',')
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Created a plunker for the same(https://plnkr.co/edit/5UBTplGR5HVQtMt3HVxZ?p=preview) . Basically, as you might have multiple ids in the list, you should check if the splitUsers contains that id or not. And as pointed out in the below answer there should be an ng-if on the underlying table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="ProfileSheet" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-if="splitusers.includes(user.ID)">
```

But a better option will be to filter the `users` array inside your controller or even inside the `ng-repeat` directive.

Comment: Can you explain how I would filter the array in the controller?

Comment: @cfoster5 It can be as simple as: `$scope.users = $scope.users.filter(user => $scope.selectedusers.includes(user.ID))`. This will increase performance because the items that don't need to be displayed won't be created at all.

Comment: Also be sure to check the variable types. Query parameters are strings, while user.ID is most likely an integer. Use `user.ID.toString()` to ensure proper comparison.